# AngularJS slider - updating labels with timeout?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider

I am trying to use AngularJS slider to slide through some date/time points. More specifically, I am using the one with draggable range, the demo presented here -  https://jsfiddle.net/ValentinH/954eve2L/

The values come from the back end and they are pulled at certain time intervals. I am storing datetime values in an array - dateTimeArray.
I was assuming that the labels (date/time points) on the slider, on the UI, should automatically be updated, when the date/time values are updated in dateTimeArray inside the controller, but they are not. Any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
            <rzslider
              rz-slider-model="slider.minValue"
              rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue"
              rz-slider-options="slider.options">
            </rzslider>
```

**JS**

```
                $scope.slider = {

                    minValue: dateTimeArray.length - 10,
                    maxValue: dateTimeArray.length - 5,

                    options: {
                        floor: 0,
                        ceil: dateTimeArray.length - 1, 

                        draggableRange: true,

                        translate: function (value) {
                            return (dateTimeArray[value]);
                        }

                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different path to update the slider values, although the initial version may have a solution too. It turned out that using just stepsArray in slider options instead of translate, solved my problem. Seems like with non numeric values, such as dates or strings, the stepsArray automatically does the work, it updates the values on the front end, whenever the array itself is updated.

```
$scope.slider = {

                minValue: dateTimeArray[3], // some min value, for example
                maxValue: dateTimeArray[7], // some max value

                options: {
                    .....
                    stepsArray :dateTimeArray,
                    ........

                    // no need for translate block

                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted my previous answer because you edited the question.

Indeed, for your use case, you can directly used the `stepsArray` option which was exactly implemented for this purpose. Also, in your case, you might want to use the `bindIndexForStepsArray` which enables you to set the index as the minValue/maxValue instead of the array value: http://jsfiddle.net/vphbr1ht/

On the other hand, with the first method you were using, you should have called

```
$scope.$broadcast('rzSliderForceRender')
```

to force the slider to refresh: http://jsfiddle.net/omhwvozb/.